# Creating a threshold-coded ROC plot in Python

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, scikit-learn, roc

R's [ROCR package](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de) provides options for ROC curve plotting that will color code and label threshold values along the curve:

[image]

The closest I can get with Python is something like

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(qualityTrain.PoorCare, qualityTrain.Pred1)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='ROC curve', color='b')
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.05])
plt.ylim([-0.05, 1.05])
```

which gives

[image]

Are there packages that provide functionality equivalent to R's ability to label (using `print.cutoffs.at`) and color code (using `colorize`) thresholds? Presumably this information is in `thresholds`, returned by [`sklearn.metrics.roc_curve`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html), but I can't figure out how to use it to color code and label the figure.

Answer (score 9):

Look at this gist:

https://gist.github.com/podshumok/c1d1c9394335d86255b8

```
roc_data = sklearn.metrics.roc_curve(...)
plot_roc(*roc_data, label_every=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sklearn # for the roc curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_roc(labels, predictions, positive_label, thresholds_every=10, title=''):
  # fp: false positive rates. tp: true positive rates
  fp, tp, thresholds = sklearn.metrics.roc_curve(labels, predictions, pos_label=positive_label)
  roc_auc = sklearn.metrics.auc(fp, tp)

  figure(figsize=(16, 16))
  plt.plot(fp, tp, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc, linewidth=2, color='darkorange')
  plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', linestyle='--', linewidth=2)
  plt.xlabel('False positives rate')
  plt.ylabel('True positives rate')
  plt.xlim([-0.03, 1.0])
  plt.ylim([0.0, 1.03])
  plt.title(title)
  plt.legend(loc="lower right")
  plt.grid(True)

  # plot some thresholds
  thresholdsLength = len(thresholds)
  colorMap=plt.get_cmap('jet', thresholdsLength)
  for i in range(0, thresholdsLength, thresholds_every):
    threshold_value_with_max_four_decimals = str(thresholds[i])[:5]
    plt.text(fp[i] - 0.03, tp[i] + 0.005, threshold_value_with_max_four_decimals, fontdict={'size': 15}, color=colorMap(i/thresholdsLength));
  plt.show()
```

Usage:

```py
labels = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
predictions = [0.7, 0.99, 0.9, 0.3, 0.7, 0.01] # predictions/accuracy for class 1
plot_roc(labels, predictions, positive_label=1, thresholds_every=1, title="ROC Curve - Class 1")
```

Result:
[plot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJukR.png)